# Compute the eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

How to calculate the eigenvalues of the following linear transformation? The solution is supposed to be the roots of unity.

Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ be a basis of $\mathbb R^n$. The transformation $T$ sends $x_i$ to $x_{i+1}$ and $x_n$ to $x_0$.

Source: This is part of reading some notes on representation theory, being new to the subject. This is a statement starting with ``it is easy to see that ... ''. This perhaps shows a personal weakness in linear algebra and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I presume $x_0$ should be $x_1$?

Comment: Do you know about the minimal or characteristic polynomials of a linear transformation?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\theta_1,...,\theta_n$ be the $n$th roots of unity. If we let $v_k = (1,\theta_k, \theta_k^2,...,\theta_k^{n-1})^T$, then $T v_k = \theta_k v_k$.
Since $v_1,...,v_n$ are linearly independent, we see that the eigenvalues are $\theta_1,...,\theta_n$.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove this fact by induction on $n$.

Another possibility is to notice that $T^n = id_{\mathbb{R}^n}$, thus all eigenvalues have norm $1$, and then try to argue by symmetry.

A third possibility is to look at the representation theory of the symmetric group $S_n$, which should give you the answer immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with the matrix representation of the map wrt the given basis:

$$\begin{align*}Tx_0&=0\cdot x_0+1\cdot x_1\\
Tx_1&=0\cdot x_0+0\cdot x_1+1\cdot x_2\\
\ldots&\ldots\ldots\ldots\\
Tx_{n-1}&=0\cdot x_0+\ldots +0\cdot x_{n-1}+1\cdot x_n\\
Tx_n&=1\cdot x_0\end{align*}$$

Thus, the matrix is

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&\ldots&0&1\\
1&0&0&\ldots&0\\
0&1&0&\ldots&0\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
0&0&\ldots&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

The above is just a permutation matrix: in fact, it is an elementary matrix (last row to first one, first row to second one, etc.).

If you want to be more "official", calculate its characteristic polynomial (we write down as lower right subindex the order of the matrix to make things, hopefully, clearer):

$$p_A(x)=\det(xI-A)=\begin{vmatrix}x&0&\ldots&0&\!\!-1\\
\!\!-1&x&0&\ldots&0\\
0&\!\!-1&x&\ldots&0\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
0&0&\ldots&\!\!-1&x\end{vmatrix}_{n+1}$$

Now, since for example with $\;n=1\;$ we get

$$\det(xI-A)=\begin{vmatrix}0&\!\!-1\\\!\!-1&x\end{vmatrix}=-1$$

or for $\;n=2\;$

$$\det(xI-A)=\begin{vmatrix}0&0&\!\!-1\\\!\!-1&x&0\\0&\!\!-1&x\end{vmatrix}=-1$$

you can develop the above inductively by successively choosing the first columns:

$$p_A(x)=x\begin{vmatrix}x&0&\ldots&0&0\\
\!\!-1&x&0&\ldots&0\\
0&\!\!-1&x&\ldots&0\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
0&0&\ldots&\!\!-1&x\end{vmatrix}_n+\begin{vmatrix}0&0&\ldots&0&\!\!-1\\
\!\!-1&x&0&\ldots&0\\
0&\!\!-1&x&\ldots&0\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
0&0&\ldots&\!\!-1&x\end{vmatrix}_n\stackrel{\text{Deter. of triang mat.}}=$$

$$=x(x^n)+\begin{vmatrix}0&0&\ldots&0&\!\!-1\\
\!\!-1&x&0&\ldots&0\\
0&\!\!-1&x&\ldots&0\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
0&0&\ldots&\!\!-1&x\end{vmatrix}_n\stackrel{\text{Ind. Hyp.}}=x^{n+1}-1$$